# MySQL - are there any benefits replacing an INT(11) UNSIGNED with a FK to INT(11) UNSIGNED that is UNIQUE?

Tags: mysql, reference, foreign-keys, int

if I do have a table `player_res`:

```
+-----------+-------+
| player_id | score |
+-----------+-------+
|     1     |   30  |
|     2     |   30  |
|     3     |   22  |
|     4     |   22  |
+-----------+-------+
```

Would it be better to have `score` being a foreign key referencing lets say `num.value`, with `num.value` being **UNIQUE**? So a certain score can only appear once in `num.value` field.

Is there advantages in database size and/or speed as both types (`player_res.score` and `num.value`) are INT(11)? I believe it doesn't matter but someone else just tried to convince me that using a second table to store the scores uniquely would be better for performance in case the table would grow really large, that's why I decided asking here!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INT(11)` are the same size as `INT` that is 4 bytes in MySQL. For integer types the value in parenthesis is just the number of digit displayed. Not the type size.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Using an secondary table to deduplicate score values doesn't seems to be a very serious idea... or you and I are *really* missing some subtleties?

---

If size is really an issue, you might perhaps use a smaller integer (like a tinyint) to store your scores?

Comment: Thank you, that is all I needed to know. I was already suspecting that INT(11) and INT have the same size, I was just confused by a friend of mine suggesting me to make a 1:M relationship table (to deduplicate).